# Source control with specific restrictions to files and folders

Tags: php, svn, version-control

I'm currently using SSH+SVN for a web project developed primarily in PHP. There is another developer working with me and we both check out from the repo into our own sandboxes which is viewable from the web.

I want to bring in new implementers and restrict them to certain parts of the project code. How do I achieve this and still allow them to have a sandbox to preview the site with their changes in it?

For example, I have a piece of code called proprietary_algo.php that needs to be restricted to only privileged developers (read, write, execute). All other new implementers can still view the site via their sandbox, which requires the execution of proprietary_algo.php, but they cannot copy the code or read the code inside of it.

I'm open to moving away from SVN or setting up a whole new process if I can achieve this.

Added note: no, NDAs and trust will not cut it. For our business need and situation, the specific source files need to be restricted.

**MORE INFO:**
I setup a virtual host and DNS that points to their sandbox dir (example: devuser1.mydomain.com) so they can do testing. They checkout code directly from trunk into their sandbox and edit code on their IDEs remotely connected via SSH. As mentioned above, there are some code in the repo that should be off limits, but still needed to run the site when they edit and test in their sandboxes. All devs share the same MySQL DB instance.

Comment: Move it to another repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you use svn+[httpd](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir).

Answer (score 0):

Addressing "requires the execution of proprietary_algo.php, but they cannot copy the code or read the code inside of it." If NDAs won't cut it, you are in for a world of pain.

Even once you've set things up with the SVN access controls, you won't be able to stop their PHP script copying the secret scripts to HTTP output.

Actually, you can stop it, but they'd have to either:

1. Call the secret script via a http request (e.g. curl). You'll need to implement an XML/JSON/name-your-HTTP-RPC-method interface between trusted and untrusted code.
2. Allow untrusted code to execute
   CGI-mode scripts.